# Is there a natural or canonical map

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, differential-geometry, inner-products, topological-groups

Is there any natural or canonical map 
$$
\begin{array}{c}
f:S^{2}\times S^{2}\times S^{2}\rightarrow S^{2}\times S^{2}\times S^{2}\\
f:\left(p_{1},p_{2},p_{3}\right)\mapsto\left(p'_{1},p'_{2},p'_{3}\right),
\end{array}
$$
where $S^{2}\subset\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is the unit sphere of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$
with the Euclidean inner product, that is some type of anti-conformal
in the sense that, for example, when $p_{1}=p_{2}=p_{3}$ one has
that $p'_{1},p'_{2},p'_{3}$ are orthogonal, and when $p_{1},p{}_{2},p{}_{3}$
are orthogonal one has that $p_{1}=p_{2}=p_{3}$? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think such a map cannot exist for topological reasons, at least if you want your map $f$ to be a homeomorphism (and if I have understood the question correctly).

The subset $A = \{(x,y,z) \in S^2 \times S^2 \times S^2 | x=y=z\}$ is homeomorphic to $S^{2}$. The subset $B = \{(x,y,x)| $x,y,z$ \text{ are pairwise orthogonal}\}$ is three dimensional- for each $x$ there is a circle of points orthogonal to $x$ in which $y$ and $z$ can vary (whilst still being orthogonal). This shows $B$ is homeomorphic to an $S^{1}$-bundle over $S^{2}$. Hence, since $A$ and $B$ are not homeomorphic, there cannot be a homeomorphism mapping $A$ to $B$.

Comment: (in fact, $B$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^3$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you explain to me why $B$ is 3-dimensional? Thanks.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thank you for your comment. Could you please explain to me why $B$ is diffeomorphic to RP^3? Thanks.

Comment: How about their quotients over the othogonal group O(3), and is there any natural or canonical map? Thanks a lot!